# Rotate 90 Degrees (Z-Axis) to Geometry Node Instances of Planes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm still new at this and I was able to accomplish what I'm looking for using the Array modifier, but I'm hoping to do the same with geometry nodes.

So I'm creating a building and the set of object instances I'm trying to rotate would be windows of that building. If I simply go to the object properties and just rotate 90 degrees on the Z axis, I'm able to rotate it the way I want, but it doesn't work the same when I go into the nodes. I've tried using Rotate Instances, Rotate Euler, Transform, and Instances on Points nodes and even unchecking "Local"/"Local Space" isn't giving me the desired result.  I see how it's wrong, but I'm having trouble with the right rotational math/calculations.

[image: Building]

[image: Node Group 1]

[image: Node Group 2]

The node groups are essentially the same and I also reset some values because I wanted to figure out the rotations so I can go ahead add in the rest of the changes. I feel like the solution is probably very simple, but I've been stuck on this.

I just want the highlighted objects to cover all four walls of the building, but using geometry nodes please.